# bootstrap 3 column grid in 1 row displaying as 1 column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying out Bootstrap at the moment and I want to have a 3 column grid in 1 row but it always displays as 1 column and 1 row, what am I doing wrong? I am using chrome.

Code:
  http://www.bootply.com/RZTdToz6bf

Comment: change your class name "span4" to "col-lg-4" on all 3 elements

Comment: @user3263978 do you have an idea why they used "span4" as class names for the coumns?

Comment: I think using spanX has been deprecated since bootstrap 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 3, you need to use the new column classes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p></div>
</div>
```

Use -md-, -lg-, etc. to apply at various viewport widths.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bootply.com/IuRailYZLP

Use col-lg-4 for your class names to make 3 columns in a single row, as using spanX has been deprecated since bootstrap 3.0